# Ubuntu or Ganache Terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm new to Ubuntu and Ganache and do not know how to open a terminal in this software.  Can anyone provide instructions on how to open a terminal in Ubuntu and/or Ganache?

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+T. This opens a terminal in Ubuntu and you can also open it from the menu.
In Ganache do you mean the log?